# Not getting full results when requesting info from a web service

Tags: java, android, json, soap

I have a written web service, and java method I wrote to call one of its methods.
The service returns a `JSON` string.

I can't post here any of the service code because of a NDA agreement, but it's also irrelevant because when activating the method from the service itself, it gives the correct results.

Basically, the java code skips the first cell in the array.

Here is the original result (directly from the service):

```
{"message":"Success","success":"1","Table" : [{"priceline" : "Price 1","percaret_price" : "1430.0000","total" : "757.9000","discount" : "-45.00"},{"priceline" : "Price 2","percaret_price" : "","total" : "","discount" : ""},{"priceline" : "Price 3","percaret_price" : "","total" : "","discount" : ""},{"priceline" : "Cash","percaret_price" : "","total" : "","discount" : ""},{"priceline" : "MSRP","percaret_price" : "","total" : "","discount" : ""}]}
```

Here is the result from the java code:

```
{"message":"Success","success":"1","Table" : [{"priceline" : "Price 2","percaret_price" : "","total" : "","discount" : ""},{"priceline" : "Price 3","percaret_price" : "","total" : "","discount" : ""},{"priceline" : "Cash","percaret_price" : "","total" : "","discount" : ""},{"priceline" : "MSRP","percaret_price" : "","total" : "","discount" : ""}]}
```

*For easier reading you can use a json viewer:
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Here is my java code (all the variables are correct. If thery wasn't there was no result returned):

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, COST_INFORMATION_NAME);
// Use this to add parameters
request.addProperty("user_id", login.getUser_id());
request.addProperty("company_id", login.getCompany_id());
request.addProperty("inventoryID", inventoryId);

// Declare the version of the SOAP request
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
envelope.dotNet = true;

try {
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
    androidHttpTransport.call(COST_INFORMATION_ACTION, envelope);

    // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
    if (result != null) {
    String res = result.getPropertyAsString(0);
            //************************************************************
            //Everything else isn't relevant, the res variable contains the result I put above the code.
            //************************************************************
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you using JSON for SOAP response ?

Comment: Of course. the result is in JSON format.

Comment: You are trying to convert JSON to Java object, and in the process the first row of the array getting skipped?

Comment: No. it looks like from the beginning it skips the first one. It is not related to the fact I am using JSON. The string I get from the service is just wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't believe it... the the inventoryID property in th service was not in capital letters...
Weird though that it made the result wrong, and didn't just gave an error..

Answer (score 0):

Have you rechecked the process of creating String form InputStream ? Encoding used may be. I am not sure if this is the reason but I had had the same problem because of it once.

Comment: Tried it. Changed the encoding, and still same problem